# How to get the job progression percentage for a particular job being processed by Mediaconvert?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I have found out that Status Interval Update Event is send to Cloudwatch event every minute when the job is progressing,the interval can be changed to 10 seconds as well.How to show the percentage at the client side from the Cloudwatch event sending events after every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to capture the STATUS_UPDATE event from CloudWatch and feed that into a service like Lambda that could update a database, or whatever data source you are using to display job stats out.

Example of the Event Pattern

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.mediaconvert"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "MediaConvert Job State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "status": [
      "STATUS_UPDATE"
    ]
  }
}
```

Example of what the Status Update event payload looks like:

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "ABC",
    "detail-type": "MediaConvert Job State Change",
    "source": "aws.mediaconvert",
    "account": "111122223333 ",
    "time": "2021-02-18T17:52:32Z",
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:mediaconvert:us-west-2:111122223333 :jobs/1613670689802-emcngz"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "timestamp": 1613670752653,
        "accountId": "111122223333 ",
        "queue": "arn:aws:mediaconvert:us-west-2:111122223333 :queues/Default",
        "jobId": "1613670689802-emcngz",
        "status": "STATUS_UPDATE",
        "userMetadata": {},
        "framesDecoded": 2024,
        "jobProgress": {
            "phaseProgress": {
                "PROBING": {
                    "status": "COMPLETE",
                    "percentComplete": 100
                },
                "TRANSCODING": {
                    "status": "PROGRESSING",
                    "percentComplete": 2
                },
                "UPLOADING": {
                    "status": "PENDING",
                    "percentComplete": 0
                }
            },
            "jobPercentComplete": 7,
            "currentPhase": "TRANSCODING",
            "retryCount": 0
        }
    }
}
```

MediaConvert provides granular percentages per phases the job is in (probing input, transcoding, and uploading outputs) as well as an overall percentage. The one that is displayed on the MediaConvert Console UI is the `jobPercentComplete`, and would probably be the one you want to capture.

Documentation: 
CloudWatch Events supported by MediaConvert:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/mediaconvert_cwe_events.html 
How to setup CloudWatch Event:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/setting-up-cloudwatch-event-rules.html